# Z3 C-API Get value of a const with no constraints

Tags: c, z3

I'm on a project using the C API of Z3 and I'm experimenting with enumeration sorts in order to restrain a constant to a set of finite values.

Now the problem is, that I won't get a value for this constant as long as there is no constraint defined for it. However at this point I already need a value returned and I'm wondering how to achieve this.

- Is there a constraint that can enforce a value to be assigned to a constant?
- Using the online evaluator I can force Z3 into returning a value anyway by doing the following:

  ```
  (echo "starting Z3...")
  (declare-datatypes () ((S A B C)))
  (declare-const a S)
  (check-sat)
  (get-value (a))
  ```

However I can't seem to get that working with the C-API. I've already tried the following:

- Put the ast from creating the const into a solver and get the model. This gives me an illegal argument error.
- Trying to get the model from the solver without setting any assertion gives me an invalid usage error

Any more ideas? I think I'm just missing out on something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet works for me:

```
using namespace z3;
void main() {
  context ctx;
  func_decl_vector cs(ctx);
  func_decl_vector ts(ctx);
  char const* abc[3] = {"A","B","C"};
  sort s = ctx.enumeration_sort("S", 3, abc, cs, ts);
  expr a = ctx.constant("a", s);
  solver so(ctx);
  so.check();
  expr b = so.get_model().eval(a, true);
  std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```

Note that I pass in the value "true" into the second argument of eval. 
This instruments the evaluator to "complete" the model even if no value was
created for 'a' when checking satisfiability (of a solver state without any assertions).
Model completion is by default "false".

Comment: This looks pretty promising. I'll try it tomorrow and tell if this works for me :)

Comment: Z3 question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566727/implement-z3-maximize-in-c